# Symfony 4 translate Entity fields

Tags: php, symfony4

I have been developing multilanguage website based on Symfony4. Structure of one of the tables:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| title_en | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| title_fr | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| title_de | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| parent_id | int(11) | NO |  | NULL |  |

What is the optimal way to select appropriate column in template depending on user locale?

How bad will look the approach below to get needed entity field?

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title_en", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $titleEn;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title_fr", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $titleFr;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title_de", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $titleDe;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $parentId = '0';

    

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLocalizedTitle(): ?string
    {
        $locale='title'.ucfirst($GLOBALS['request']->getLocale());
        return  $this->{$locale};
    }

    public function getTitleEn(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titleEn;
    }

    public function setTitleEn(string $titleEn): self
    {
        $this->titleEn = $titleEn;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitleDe(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titleDe;
    }

    public function setTitleDe(string $titleDe): self
    {
        $this->titleDe = $titleDe;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getParentId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->parentId;
    }

    public function setParentId(int $parentId): self
    {
        $this->parentId = $parentId;

        return $this;
    }

  
}
```

Then in view to get field we just use

```
{{ job.category.getLocalizedTitle }}
```

Comment: This code already works and suggests improvements based on better performance and readability

Comment: I think this isn't a sustainable approach that will scale well. Consider keying your resources with an ID *and* a language code instead; that way adding support for a new language doesn't require schema + code changes, just the new data.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Something like a single JSON per language?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon are you willing to turn your comment into an answer? As you likely are aware: [short answers are okay](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/120114)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ done!

Answer (score 2):

I think this isn't a sustainable approach that will scale well. Consider keying your resources with an ID *and* a language code instead; that way adding support for a new language doesn't require schema + code changes, just the new data.

In other words you would have an instance of this entity *per supported language*, a property that can identify the language it's for, and only one `title` property, without any language code suffix.